# Button Clicked Event was triggered Twice or More in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, click

I added a button on a section and wrote clicked event

```
var refreshCacheSettings = new CustomButtonSection ("GeneralSettingsView_RefreshCache_Button_Title".t());

            refreshCacheSettings.ButtonClicked += async (sender, e) => {

                Console.WriteLine ("Clicked...");
                var btn = (UIButton)sender;
                btn.Enabled=false;
                btn.UserInteractionEnabled =false;

                var answer= await AlertUtil.CreateMessageYesNo("GeneralSettingsView_RefreshCache_Question_Title".t(),"GeneralSettingsView_RefreshCache_Question_Message".t());

                if(!answer)
                {
                    ShowLoadingScreen();
                    await Task.Run(()=> RefreshFormFieldSettings());
                }


                btn.Enabled=true;
                btn.UserInteractionEnabled =true;

            };
```

and here is custom button section class

```
public class CustomButtonSection : RootElement
{
    string _btnText;
    public event EventHandler ButtonClicked;
    public CustomButtonSection (string btnText):base ("")
    {
        base.MakeViewController ();
        _btnText = btnText;

    }


    protected override UIViewController MakeViewController ()
    {
        var vc = (UITableViewController) base.MakeViewController();

        vc.TableView.BackgroundView = null;
        vc.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White; //or whatever color you like
        return vc;
    }

    public override void Selected (DialogViewController dvc, UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath path)
    {
        base.Deselected (dvc, tableView, path);
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tv)
    {

        var cell = tv.DequeueReusableCell ("CustomCell") as CustomButtonCell;
        if (cell == null)
            cell = new CustomButtonCell (new NSString("CustomCell"));

        cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
        cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
        cell.UpdateCell (_btnText);
        cell.btn.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
            if (ButtonClicked != null) 
                ButtonClicked (sender, e);

        };
        return cell;

    } 


    private class CustomButtonCell: UITableViewCell
    {
        public UIButton btn;


        public CustomButtonCell(NSString cellId )
            : base(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
        {
            SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
            Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
            ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
            btn = ImagewareMobile.iOS.UI.Common.Buttons.ElementsButton("", FitpulseTheme.SharedTheme.BlueButtonImage);


        ContentView.AddSubviews(new UIView[] {btn});

        }

        public void UpdateCell (string caption )
        {
            btn.SetTitle(caption,UIControlState.Normal);

        }

        public override void LayoutSubviews ()
        {
            base.LayoutSubviews ();
            btn.SetTitleColor(UIColor.White, UIControlState.Normal);
            btn.Frame = new CGRect (5,5,300,35);

        }
    }

}
```

Sometimes I got the alert message twice or more times. It doesnt happen all time but sometimes happens and it is boring..

in javascript there is preventDefault method, but what about for ios?

I am using xamarin.ios with c# but I can handle code of objective C or swift.

Comment: Please can you confirm if the issue gets worse when you scroll or if you go out of the screen and back in? I have a feeling you're registering your button click multiple times

Comment: @Webmonger, thank you for your reply. I checked event is null all time, if you look above, I create button everytime with new (var refreshCacheSettings = new CustomButtonSection ("GeneralSettingsView_RefreshCache_Button_Title".t());
)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that you apply the event every time the cell will be reused.

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tv)
{

    var cell = tv.DequeueReusableCell ("CustomCell") as CustomButtonCell;
    if (cell == null)
        cell = new CustomButtonCell (new NSString("CustomCell"));

    cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
    cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
    cell.UpdateCell (_btnText);

    // this is the reason for multiple events fired
    cell.btn.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
        if (ButtonClicked != null) 
            ButtonClicked (sender, e);

    };
    return cell;

}
```

It would be better to change your code to

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tv)
{

    var cell = tv.DequeueReusableCell ("CustomCell") as CustomButtonCell;
    if (cell == null)
    {
        cell = new CustomButtonCell (new NSString("CustomCell"));
        cell.btn.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
        if (ButtonClicked != null) 
            ButtonClicked (sender, e);

        };
    }
    cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
    cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
    cell.UpdateCell (_btnText);

    return cell;

}
```

That way the event will be attached only if the cell will be newly created.

Comment: thank you for your answer.It seems the problem is solved with that code.